# Can't register a domain due to trademark

Tags: domains, domain-registration, trademark

I attempted to register `crack.house`.  I was told that I could not (by namecheap), because "the domain name contains a trademark".

How often does this happen, and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. They are right.

Here it is: http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4801:2tk3qv.2.2

You do not want to register a trademark as a domain name. One can argue locale in some respects, however, this is a company that offers...

> Printing fonts that can be downloaded provided by means of electronic
>   transmission

...which means that locale does not come into play. They will always have a claim against your domain name registration.

This is not something you want to get into. It could mean a Federal lawsuit which always means at least $10k to begin defending even when you roll over and say "I give." Otherwise, you would at least lose your domain name even if they do not make a claim in court. It is a big risk that I advise against.

Comment: Yeah, I get you.  The thing that bothers me about it though is that companies might hold hundreds of trademarks.  Does that mean the domain space will become increasingly depleted?  Does that mean if one of the domain names I hold now becomes a trademark in the future that it may be taken away from me?  That's the kind of things that are irking me about this.

Comment: If you registered a domain name prior to a trademark, they have no claim. As well, not all trademark holders can make a claim- it depends upon the trademark and the domain name. Most trademark owners do not have any interest in registering a domain and will just let it go as long as you are not trampling upon their trademark. Which is the point. Actually, it is possible to argue that the trademark issued should be invalidated due to it being a common term. Trademarks are not to be ordinary terms and challenges can be made and won based upon this.

Comment: Trademark infringement is a very board legal law, you can use a dictionary word that is trademarked if the service/products are not associated with the orginal trademark.. i.e confusing for consumers... for example APPLE you wouldn't be allowed to sell software/hardware, as that could confuse consumers, however you could have a BAR called APPLE...

Comment: @SimonHayter I admit that it has been so long since I dealt with trademarks. You are right that there are dictionary terms registered as trademarks and conditions where one can successfully register and use a trademark, however, they can be easily challenged simply because it is not supposed to happen- really- even though there are carve-outs. A trademark is something you create. Where Apple works is where they do not then challenge everyone in the world for using Apple. McDonalds  sued someone in the UK for infringing on their trademark and lost when Lord McDonald who ran a restaurant...

Comment: @SimonHayter ... for some 600-700 years throughout the family history. McDonalds was in danger of losing their Trademark. It was a name. Names and common words are vulnerable. Though like you said, there are some carve-outs. But the carve-outs do not mean you are safe. I dealt with a challenge years ago and won. I forget what the term was or the circumstances, but it was a common term and easily challenged. I did not even need a claim though my client had a valid one. The treat of a legal challenge was enough to get a hearing and we won without making a claim.

Comment: @closetnoc McDonalds is not a dictionary word. Crack and House are both dictionary words. Dictionary word Trademarks are treated complete different than fiction, surnames and names.

Comment: And "crack house" is a commonly used phrase that is mostly used without reference to the organization that holds the trademark.

Comment: @SimonHayter McDonald is a name. It is like my name. My last name was granted by decree from the King of Scotland a long time ago. Our family has never been huge. The name has never been licensed, granted, loaned, or given and yet it is everywhere being used commercially without trace back to ownership. We and others here in the U.S. wanted Lord McDonald to make the claim so that the *fact* can be nailed down once and for all. It is a clear-cut case. Lord McDonald would have won easily without a protracted challenge. It would have helped to clean-up our family name which has been abused.

Comment: @SimonHayter It is an example of ownership and why common terms cannot be used. Apple does not own the right to the word. But because there are limitations and Apple behaves itself, it is permitted. I think crack house could be challenged push comes to shove, but it would cost money and may not be worth it. Certainly a challenge cannot be made so that someone else can register crack house as a trademark. It does not work that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t operate in the exact same market segment as the trademark holder, then use another domain registrar to register the name that you want. The only way to violate the trademark would be if, for example, they sell cars and you sell cars.

It might be that every single word in the English dictionary now has a trademark applied to it somewhere in the world. But again, those trademarks only restrict a direct competitor in each particular market segment.